# Is iOS metal 3d texture sample method trilinear?

Tags: ios, shader, metal, lookup-tables, 3d-texture

I am using a color lookup table to create a 3d texture, and use input color to find output color. but I found output color has some interrupt layer. Is this sampler sample 3d texture by using trilinear?

This is my code for creating 3d texture

the **lutData** is an array of r, g, b, a, r, g, b, a, ....

**lutSize** is the lookup table size, it's 32 or 64.

```
func create3DTextureFromLutData(lutData: [Float], lutSize: Int) -> MTLTexture? {
    let desc = MTLTextureDescriptor()
    desc.textureType = .type3D
    desc.pixelFormat = .rgba32Float
    desc.width = lutSize
    desc.height = lutSize
    desc.depth = lutSize
    desc.usage = .shaderRead
     
    guard let texture = _device.makeTexture(descriptor: desc) else { return nil}
     
    texture.replace(region: MTLRegion(origin: .init(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0), size: .init(width: lutSize, height: lutSize, depth: lutSize)), mipmapLevel: 0, slice: 0, withBytes: lutData, bytesPerRow: lutSize * MemoryLayout<Float>.size * 4, bytesPerImage: lutSize * lutSize * MemoryLayout<Float>.size * 4)
     
    return texture
  }
```

And in my shader, I just want to sample it like this.

```
constexpr sampler textureSampler = sampler(mag_filter::linear, min_filter::linear, mip_filter::linear, address::clamp_to_edge);
half4 lutWith3dTexture(half4 inputColor, short lutSize, half lutStrength, texture3d<float, access::sample> lut3dTexture, sampler textureSampler) {
  half4 originColor = inputColor;
  float3 coor = float3(((inputColor.rgb * (lutSize - 1)) + 0.5) / lutSize);
  half4 resultColor = half4(lut3dTexture.sample(textureSampler, coor));
   
  return mix(originColor, resultColor, lutStrength);
}
```

I am trying a different filter::xxxx didn't help anything.

This is a good result, the interpolation is very smooth.

[image: Imgur]

And this is the bad result with 3d texture sample.

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 1):

In general - yes, trilinear interpolation is supported by Metal on iOS, but only on some pixel formats.
Looking at the [feature set table](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Feature-Set-Tables.pdf) you can see filtering is not supported on RGBA32Float (or generally on any Float32 texture). Changing to a RGBA16Float or RGBA8Unorm should solve your issue.